# Display column on click of button in Datatable

Tags: jquery, html-table, datatables, click

I am using Datatable - table plugin for JQuery - as following :

```
$('#my_table').DataTable({
    ...,

    "aoColumns": [
        {"bSortable": false,
            render: function (data, type, row, meta) {
                return meta.row + meta.settings._iDisplayStart + 1;
            } 
        },
        {"bSortable": false},
        {"bSortable": false},
        {"bSortable": false},
        {"bSortable": true, bVisible:false}, /* to hide */
        {"bSortable": false},
    ],
    ...
});
```

As one can see in the code,the 5th column is hidden. I want to show this column on a click of button. Can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can hide/show the column as below:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var table = $('#my_table').DataTable();
    table.column(4).visible(true);
});
```

Another way is

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    var table = $('#my_table').DataTable();
    table.fnSetColumnVis( 4, true );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add an external event like .onClick('element') in a button or attach it to the row identifier that listens and change the bVisible property, or perhaps, you can also incude a callback function in the object property to perform the change : `{"bSortable": true, bVisible:function(){/*listen to click event on a specific element*/}},`

note that maybe you will need to render the table again, since it have trouble dealing with incomplete tables and functionalities maybe are truncated, i'll get back with more info.